# Detect mock location in flutter

Tags: flutter, gps, location, mock-location

Hi I am trying to detect wether user is using fake gps or not using `trust_location` and `geolocator` package. For `geolocator` package, as I know it has property of `isMocked`. So, when I open my apps and then turning on the fake gps, it success to return `true` that user is using fake gps. But the problem is.... I will get different result when I turn on fake gps for the first, and the second I open my apps... it will return `false`. It means that the fake gps is not detected... Is there another way to detect mock location of user ?

Answer (score 3):

Your Geolocator must return a position object. From this object, you will find an option called isMocked. That will work perfectly for sure.

Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
desiredAccuracy: gl.LocationAccuracy.high);

position.isMocked.

hope this will help you.